# Upgrade to 20.04 has come with a bar at the bottom

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 20.04

I upgraded to 20.04 (GNOME desktop) from 18.04 yesterday. Everything went smoothly but I have a bar that I previously didn't have at the bottom of the screen. It seems to be something related to workspaces. I'd like to hide it but i can't find a way to. Nothing in GNOME Tweaks or the OS settings etc. So does anyone know how to get rid?

[image: screenshot with bottom bar]]

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12

drwxrwxr-x 3 dave dave 4096 Feb 24  2019 .
drwx------ 3 dave dave 4096 Aug 16 00:29 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 dave dave 4096 Feb 24  2019 dynamicTopBar@gnomeshell.feildel.fr
```

---

```
$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 68

drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Aug 14 23:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Aug 15 00:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 23:51 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:03 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:16 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: You've probably added a GNOME Shell extension that does that. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to get rid of that beautiful bar?!?!?! Honestly, I don't understand what you have there??? It looks like Unity, but with flashback bars? I'm curious, are those bars movable, can they both be put on the bottom? If Unity would have looked like that when it first came out I would have never went to flashback! Maybe you can try `gsettings list-recursively | grep panel` and see if there are other panels settings there you can use to remove. Their location will show so you can find them in 'Tweaks' or you can use the 'gsettings set' command to alter them.

Comment: @heynnema ... is that not the Unity desktop??? I went away from it(to flashback) as SOON as ubuntu looked like a tablet so I have almost no knowledge of those variations? Was there a intentional way to get functional bars on that desktop??

Comment: @heynnema Ive added the requested outputs to my question

Comment: @WU-TANG do feel free to ask a question about how to get this bar if you want (it would help to link to this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bar looks like a GNOME extension. I have a bar exactly like that enabled on my desktop. Try looking in GNOME Tweaks under extensions.

`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 14 22:15 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` is likely the culprit.

Comment: Yep you were right it was that extension. Thanks!

Comment: I have disabled `window-list` from Tweaks under extensions however I still see the bar at the bottom

Comment: Ok looks like mine is the default behaviour in Gnome classic, I logged out and logged into `Ubuntu Default` session and it dissapeared \0/